# Is there an easy way to retrospectively turn Emacs numbered versions of software into git versions?

Tags: git, version-control

I have some files from an open source project which I edited somewhat, e.g.

```
 Makefile
 Makefile.~1~
 Makefile.~2~
```

These numbered versions are made by Emacs with its numbered version control and are like VMS versioned files

I understand that the Linux project and Perl language project retrospectively put their oldest versions under version control. I would like to retrospectively add the files as untarred from the .tar.gz tarball file and the numbered versions into a version-controlled system.

Is there any relatively easy or simple way to do such a thing? How would I go about writing a script to automate this process?

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what you have - you mention both tarballs and numbered version files. And for the numbered files, I'm not sure if I know how you want them committed - does `Makefile.~2~` go with `other.file~2~`? Or do you have nice convenient tarballs for each old state? If you can clarify, I'm sure I can help you automate it.

Comment: @Jefromi: I have files which are version-controlled via numbering which I want to retrospectively put under git version control.

Comment: @Master of Disaster: so you only have one `.tar.gz` file containing the source and Emacs backup files, rather than multiple tar files for different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that your numbered files all match up - i.e. `foo.~3~`  and `bar.~3~` are from the same overall version. If they aren't, I don't see how you possibly have enough information to construct a meaningful history. And of course, let's also assume all these numbered files are in one directory, possibly bottled up in that tarball that you mention.

The following isn't totally perfect, but it certainly worked on my test case. (It doesn't properly deal with hidden files which exist in one version but not the next - change that `rm -rf *` to something shinier if you care about that.)

```
#!/bin/bash

old_directory=/path/to/numbered_files_dir
repo_dir=/path/to/repo_to_create

empty_repo() {
    (
    cd "$repo_dir" &&
        rm -rf *
    )
}

commit_all() {
    (
    cd "$repo_dir" &&
    git add -A &&
    git commit -e -m "$1"
    )
}


mkdir -p "$repo_dir" && (cd "$repo_dir" && git init)

# note: sort -u gave incorrect results for me here. very strange.
for n in $(find "$old_directory" | grep -o '~[0-9]\+~$' | sort -rn | uniq); do
    echo "version $n"
    empty_repo
    for f in $(find "$old_directory" -type f -name "*.$n" -printf '%P\n'); do
        mkdir -p "$repo_dir/$(dirname "$f")"
        cp "$old_directory/$f" "$repo_dir/${f%.$n}"
    done
    commit_all "version $n"
done

empty_repo
for f in $(find $old_directory -type f -not -regex '.*\.~[0-9]+~$' -printf '%P\n'); do
    mkdir -p "$repo_dir/$(dirname "$f")"
    cp "$old_directory/$f" "$repo_dir/$f"
done
commit_all "final version"
```

Comment: If the version numbers don't match up, you are still not completely lost, provided that the time stamps on the files are correct: One could use the ordering provided by the time stamps to create the commits.

Comment: @cebewee: In which case you'd probably just write the script as "list the files in this directory, sorted by date, and for each one, move it into the repo (stripping the suffix), and commit - thus completely ignoring the numbering. You might still be in trouble on deleted files.

Comment: @cebewee: But of course, there's then a good chance a lot of your commits won't be valid states, since frequently changes in one file necessitate changes in another. I guess you could, before committing, run some kind of test (see if it builds?) and if it fails, move on to the next file without committing.

Comment: Of course, but that's what you get when using a version control scheme based on single files. But you wouldn't be worse off then in the current state.

Comment: OK, I see the idea you have used and I can take it from there. Thanks.